# How to fill child items height by other side by side height;

Tags: css

I'm trying to do some blocks with css and html, few of them have fixed height for example like you see 200px, but others need to be dynamic/flexible and need to be stretched by others height. C, G, H blocks need to be dynamic and stretches by opposite blocks max current height with content. In picture you see that blocks goes out of zone, C, G, H blocks need to be in height where red line is drawed;

Image what i want to say
[image: Image what i want to say]

```css
.clearFix {
  clear: both;
}


/*        Header blocks    */

.headerBlockSection {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.block-A {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 3) - 10px);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block-B {
  width: calc(100% / 4 * 1);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008000;
  float: left;
}


/*        Main content sections    */

.mainContentSection {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.contentSection-1 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 1));
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

.contentSection-2 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 2) - 20px);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.contentSection-3 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 1));
  float: left;
}


/*        Left    */

.block-C {
  background-color: #f8eb3a;
  height: 100%;
}


/*        Middle    */

.block-D {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #316266;
}

.block-E {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #316266;
}

.block-G {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #316266;
  height: 100%;
}


/*
        Right
    */

.block-F {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #801a00;
}

.block-H {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #801a00;
  height: 100%;
}


/*        Footer blocks    */

.block-I {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9ad7ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="headerBlockSection">
    <div class="block-A">A</div>
    <div class="block-B">B</div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
  </header>

  <section class="mainContentSection">
    <div class="contentSection-1">
      <div class="block-C"> C </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentSection-2">
      <div class="block-D">D</div>
      <div class="block-E">E</div>
      <div class="block-G"> G </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentSection-3">
      <div class="block-F">F</div>
      <div class="block-H">H</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
  </section>

  <div class="block-I">I</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please take a look at CSS flex-box and CSS grid as they will both offer you much better ways to create layouts. Grid is the better, but won’t work in browsers more than a couple of years old 
https://gridbyexample.com/ https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something like [this](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/BeQBNM)?

```
.mainContentSection {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;   /* I added this value*/
}
```

Here is the full code. I also add some text at G section to make it clear.

```css
.clearFix {
  clear: both;
}


/*        Header blocks    */

.headerBlockSection {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.block-A {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 3) - 10px);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block-B {
  width: calc(100% / 4 * 1);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008000;
  float: left;
}


/*        Main content sections    */

.mainContentSection {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; /* I added this value*/
}

.contentSection-1 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 1));
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

.contentSection-2 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 2) - 20px);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.contentSection-3 {
  width: calc((100% / 4 * 1));
  float: left;
}


/*        Left    */

.block-C {
  background-color: #f8eb3a;
  height: 100%;
}


/*        Middle    */

.block-D {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #316266;
}

.block-E {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #316266;
}

.block-G {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #316266;
  height: 100%;
}


/*         Right     */

.block-F {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #801a00;
}

.block-H {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #801a00;
  height: 100%;
}


/*        Footer blocks    */

.block-I {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9ad7ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="headerBlockSection">
    <div class="block-A">A</div>
    <div class="block-B">B</div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
  </header>

  <section class="mainContentSection">
    <div class="contentSection-1">
      <div class="block-C"> C </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentSection-2">
      <div class="block-D">D</div>
      <div class="block-E">E</div>
      <div class="block-G"> G <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quas ullam ad eveniet ratione maiores fuga sapiente alias repellendus dolor sequi voluptate quaerat aliquam ut totam, perspiciatis cupiditate molestias? Tempora!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentSection-3">
      <div class="block-F">F</div>
      <div class="block-H">H</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
  </section>

  <div class="block-I">I</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Here is a link on good article about [overflow](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/). Hope it will help you a lot to understand how it works.